# Touchpad on Arch Linux / Xorg funny - cursor moves to wherever I touch the pad

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, touchpad

i am using arch linux with xorg on a laptop.

When I put my finger on the touchpad, the cursor moves to the same place on the screen. So when i touch the middle of the pad, the cursor moves to the middle of the screen; It feels like it is a touch screen and not a map.

Is this a bug or a misconfiguration? Can anyone help me?

The touchpad should move the cursor relative to where the cursor is, and not where i touch the pad exactly.

xinput shows this:

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (138):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (140): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (270): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (271):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (272):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (273):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (258):    2, 14
    Device Node (259):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (274): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (275):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (276):  0
    Axis Labels (277):  "Abs MT Position X" (267), "Abs MT Position Y" (268), "Abs MT Pressure" (269), "Abs Tool Width" (265), "Abs MT Touch Major" (266), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0)
    Button Labels (278):    "Button Left" (141), "Button Unknown" (261), "Button Unknown" (261), "Button Wheel Up" (144), "Button Wheel Down" (145)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (279): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (280):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (281):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (282): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (283): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (284):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (285):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (286):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (287):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (288):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (289):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (290): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (291):  0
```

Comment: `synclient -l` output?  That sounds like a synaptics touchpad configured as a tablet.

Comment: yes, that is a better way to put it. it is behaving as a tablet. @grochmal

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed by installing xf86-input-synaptics:

```
pacman -S xf86-input-synaptics
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought you were missing.  This is correct (+1), but it would make for a better answer to add the reasoning behind it: synaptics is what adds the shared lib that makes Xorg understand a synaptics touchpad as a touchpad.

Comment: what if our device is not made by synaptics? My touchpad's from ALPS